# ASP Query value into link and name

Tags: asp-classic, hyperlink

I'm having trouble wiht an ASP Classic code that is very simple and its working in other pages.

I'm passing a value from a table into a link and showing that value in the name of the link

If i put it like this:

```
<a href="http://<%=rs("something")%>"><%=rs("something")%></a>
```

This should get the value into the name of the link and the same value into the link it self.
But it doesn't.
If I remove the tag  it will show me the ("something") but without anchoring anywhere. 
If I put the  tag like i have in the sample above, it will show nothing, just an empty space.

Comment: What is the content returned by rs("something")?

Comment: an IP address, but the value without the <a> tag works and if I write something between the <a> </a> instead of the <%rs%> it will work. The only problem is if I try to use both <%rs%> at the same time.

Comment: Would you be willing to show us more of the code around that line, please?

Comment: ` </tr>
     <% While not Rs.EOF
      Dim IP
      IP = rs("scope")
      
      Dim host 
       host= rs("hostname")
     %>
     
    <tr class="selection imgButton2">
     <td class="center"><%=host%></td>
                    <td class="center"><a href="http://<%=IP%>"><%=IP%></a></td>
     <td class="center"><%=Rs("macaddress")%></td>
    </tr>
    <%  Rs.MoveNext
                    Wend %>`

Answer (score 1):

can you put the value into a variable first, and then use that variable for the anchoring ?

ie.something like :

```
Dim ip
ip = rs("something")
```

and later on,

```
<a href="http://<%=ip%>"><%=ip%></a>
```

Comment: It will be because "something" field in the database is a text field you can do this with varchar and int fields but with text you can only call them once so if you need to use them again you must add them into a variable as SearchAndResQ says

Comment: I've tried using the variable and the result is almost the same. The first field with an <%rs%> query doesn't shows.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help. Problem solved. 
The table on SQL had  the column  IP defined has Varchar(MAX) that was the problem. I think in this case the Varchar have the samne behave has Nvarchar it shows all the 255 chars including the empty ones. That's why on the page the field was empty. It was only showing a small amout of the 255 chars.